# SharePoint Versioning restriction & customize

Tags: sharepoint-designer, versioning

With regards to SharePoint 2007 versioning feature:

1. Is it possible to put restriction on who can delete the version of a
   changed item in a SharePoint List?
2. Can the versioning be apply to new item?
   Example: Suppose there are 3 items created inside a SharePoint List, it will be called Version 1. Later, someone add 5 new items into a SharePoint List, this will result in Version 2. So, if the admin notice that the 5 new items are invalid entry, it can simply delete Version 2.
3. Is it possible to delete certain version for a particular item in a
   SharePoint List?

Comment: This question was cross posted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343440/sharepoint-versioning-restriction-customize/7344215#7344215

Comment: Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343440/sharepoint-versioning-restriction-customize/7344215#7344215 has been changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. You can customize or create new permission roles (ex. you can customize the contribute role to disallow deleteing items)  See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permission-levels-HA010117209.aspx
2. Versioning is applied on a per-item basis.  So, in your example, each Item would be at version 1 when uploaded.  Suppose an item is edited, then checked in and published as a major version.  That item is now version 2 while the other items are still version 1.  Batch deletes based on version like you suggest is pointless.  Instead, just delete the items individually.
3. Yes.  See the answer to #1.  One of the customizable abilities is the ability to delete versions.

Comment: For Q1, actually what I mean was if there was a change of a particular item, the version for that item will increment. (e.g. suppose a new item is created, it will be version 1. later, someone edit it, it become version 2.) so is it possible to restrict from deleting the whole version history for a particular item? (I hope that I did not misinterpret your answer - do let me know if I really do.)

Comment: Yes, you can do that,  See my answer to Q1.  Its the same thing, you can customize the ability to delete version history.